# Why does TextBlock.Foreground attribute work in the ContentPresenter even before TextBlock comes along?

Tags: wpf, xaml

While I was looking at the example codes of WPF in ms docs reference page I saw a XAML segment just look like below.

```
<ContentPresenter 
  Margin="10" 
  Content="{TemplateBinding  Content}" 
  TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
```

The source is here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-animate-in-a-controltemplate

My question is, at the last line there's TextBlock.Foreground setting in the ContentPresenter. But I don't see any TextBlock element around anywhere, and this seems to be working just fine. I don't get it.
How can this be working in the first place? Could someone please tell my why, please?

Comment: See the Remarks section on the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.foreground(v=vs.110).aspx): *This dependency property also has an attached property usage. In XAML, the usage is <object TextBlock.Foreground="value".../>, where object is an object element (typically a flow element) contained within a TextBlock, and value is a string that resolves to a Brush implementation value. ...*

Comment: See [Attached Properties Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview) for further details.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I think that remark doesn't explain how above contentpresenter element includes attached property about text block when no text block is around.

Comment: Below the Remarks is a section *Dependency Property Information*. You'll notice that the [FrameworkPropertyMetadata.Inherits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata.inherits(v=vs.110).aspx) flag is set, which means that the value of the Foreground property is inherited by child elements in the visual tree.